# how to select a id or a value that is common to multiple values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-1.2

this is my problem

```
book student_id
1     1
2     2
3     3
1     2
```

in this case i want book 1 since it is common to the combination of student 1 and 2(the number of students to match may change)

how can in get the book that is common to two or more students based on the combination.is there any way to make these values act like temporary columns

Answer (score 0):

You just use `group by` with `having`:

```
select book
from table t
group by book
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you can have duplicates in the table (same student and same book), then the last line should be:

```
having count(distinct student_id) > 1;
```

Comment: thank you for the response but this is not the case .think of an imaginary function where I only pass student ids and get the book id that belong to that combination a combination have only one book.and you cant add a grouping column